# Adding editor with script throws 'Invalid email' and stops script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms, google-workspace

I'm using Apps Script to generate a document including responses from a Google form and store this in a new folder. I also enable the user submitting the form editor access based on the email they provide.

`.addEditor(email);`

This seems to work for Google domains or company domains using g-suite.

When the email is not Google based however, the script breaks.

`'Invalid email: email@example.com'`

Looking for a means of skipping past this error and having the script complete.

```
  function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[1];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID');
  var folder = createfolder(); 
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Name + ' - Document', folder); 
  var newId = copy.getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId).addEditor(email);
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', Timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{Email}}', Email);  
  doc.saveAndClose();                                             


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking for a means of skipping past this error and having the script
> complete.

If you are looking for a solution to **skip** the error, then you can always use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

```
  function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var email = e.values[1];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID');
  var folder = createfolder(); 
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Name + ' - Document', folder); 
  var newId = copy.getId();
  
  try{
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId).addEditor(email);
  }
  catch(error){
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId);
  }
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{Timestamp}}', Timestamp); 
  body.replaceText('{{Email}}', Email);  
  doc.saveAndClose();                                             
  
}
```

This snippet will `try` to execute `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId).addEditor(email);`.

If the latter fails, then it will just open the document `var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newId);` and continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks Marios, I do actually want the rest of the code to continue to execute though, so if there is an error with the email, it continues to complete the replace text function

Comment: @EwanFarry Thanks for your feedback. Please try my updated solution.